# How to change line thickness in iText?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm drawing images to pdf using Java framework iText. I need to draw lines of specified width. There is a method [`setLineWidth(float width)`](http://api.itextpdf.com/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfContentByte.html#setLineWidth%28float%29) in class [`PdfContentByte`](http://api.itextpdf.com/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfContentByte.html) that should change it. However no matter what value I pass as its parameter the lines drawn are always extra thin.

There is following line in javadoc of `setLineWidth`:

> The line width specifies the thickness of the line used to stroke a path and is measured in user space units.

I don't know what is "space unit". Everything else in iText seems to be measured in point(around 1/72 inch). I cant find any reference to what are those "space units" and how to change them.

code:

```
to.setLineWidth(thickness);
to.moveTo(x, y);
to.lineTo(x + 100, y + 100);
```

Variable `to` contains instance of `PdfContentByte`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solved. There was no stroke method call after lineTo call. That's why it used another line width set just before stoke method was called.
Correct code look like this:

```
to.setLineWidth(thickness);
to.moveTo(x, y);
to.lineTo(x + 100, y + 100);
to.stroke();
```